# On-the-fly encryption volume for iOS similar to TrueCrypt

Tags: ios, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

Does anyone know if there is library like TrueCrypt or EncFS for iOS.

Purpose is to create an encrypted volume to store large files like video's securely on the device, and play them whilst decrypting at runtime.

Want to be able to do this without relying on use entering a PIN for the inbuilt file protection. and be able to make use of AES-256 for the encryption.

If there is nothing, how would I go about writing or porting my own?

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are considered off-topic in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS architecture doesn't allow "disk encryption". However, if your code can do custom playback by passing the actual data to the player (in opposite to passing file name to the player), you can make use of our [Solid File System](https://www.eldos.com/solfs/) product. This is a virtual file system with encryption and compression which you can embed into your application. Maybe that will work for you.

But encryption is just one side of the story - as you are passing the data and supposedly the encryption key to the users' hands, you need to take special actions to protect that key. This means that the key should be obfuscated within your application (or better streamed from the server) and also the parts of the data should better be encrypted with different keys.

Comment: This is true, the playback isn't a problem as we can simulate HLS locally using NSURLProtocol's and stream chunks. protecting the key's is another part of the puzzle, but that's a separate problem to solve. Your product looks interesting does it encrypt with aes256? I don't see mention of crypto methods within your site.

Comment: @user2743622 Yes, AES256 is used for encryption. This is mentioned on Technical Specification page in the product section of the site.

Comment: The Technical Specifications section is just marketing speak. AES-256 instead of AES-128 is typically an alarming sign of marketing reasons overriding technical decisions – first, because AES-256 noticeable slower (AES-128 would offer better performance yet your "high-performance file system" uses a slower cipher), and second, because it offers no real security benefit whatsoever (particularly when the keys are derived from passwords).

Comment: Use of a pseudonym is also an alarming sign of a person having something to hide <g>